# Need to Hot Reload flutter app every time in order to fetch data from Firebase realtime database

Tags: flutter, dart

**Here is my code:**

```
class CategoryHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoryHomeScreenState createState() => _CategoryHomeScreenState();
}

class _CategoryHomeScreenState extends State<CategoryHomeScreen> {

  List<CategoriesOnly> categoriesOnlyList =[];
  List<CategoryItems> categoryItemList = [];



@override
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getCategoriesName();
    super.initState();

  }
  Future<void> getCategoriesName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var userPin = prefs.getString('pin');

    var CategoryName =  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('CategoryNames').child(userPin).once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      var key  = dataSnapshot.value.keys;
      for(var i in key)
      {
       // print(dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name']);
        CategoriesOnly categoriesOnly = new CategoriesOnly(
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name']
        );
        categoriesOnlyList.add(categoriesOnly);
      }

    });

    var categoryItemDetails =  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Categories').child(userPin).once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      var key  = dataSnapshot.value.keys;
      for(var i in key)
      {
        CategoryItems categoryItems = new CategoryItems(
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['CategoryName'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['MarketPrice'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['OurPrice'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['TotalDiscount'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['Weight']

        );
        categoryItemList.add(categoryItems);
      }

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.black, //or set color with: Color(0xFF0000FF)
    ));
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(

        child:
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: categoriesOnlyList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index1) =>
              Column(children: [
                Text(categoriesOnlyList[index1].Name,style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child:
                  ListView.builder(itemCount: categoryItemList.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                       return categoriesOnlyList[index1].Name == categoryItemList[index].CategoryName?
                         Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 200,
                            width: 200,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                            child: Card(
                              color: Colors.white,
                                child: Text(categoryItemList[index]
                                .Name,style: TextStyle(),overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,)),
                          ),
                        ):Container(
                       );
                      }),
                ),

              ]),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my app where I'm loading data from firebase realtime database. When I install the app it doesn't show any data but when I reload(hot reload) the app it shows all the data and when I quit the app and again launch it I'm not able to see the data again. But I want my page to show some loading widget until it loads the data and then return the page. Or simple the page with data.

Answer (score 1):

Likely because categoryItemList.length is 0.

you can check this using the debugger or display something when the length is 0.

```dart
class CategoryHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoryHomeScreenState createState() => _CategoryHomeScreenState();
}

class _CategoryHomeScreenState extends State<CategoryHomeScreen> {
  List<CategoriesOnly> categoriesOnlyList = [];
  List<CategoryItems> categoryItemList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getCategoriesName();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getCategoriesName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var userPin = prefs.getString('pin');

    var CategoryName = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('CategoryNames')
        .child(userPin)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      var key = dataSnapshot.value.keys;
      for (var i in key) {
        // print(dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name']);
        CategoriesOnly categoriesOnly =
            new CategoriesOnly(dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name']);
        categoriesOnlyList.add(categoriesOnly);
      }
    });

    var categoryItemDetails = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('Categories')
        .child(userPin)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      var key = dataSnapshot.value.keys;
      for (var i in key) {
        CategoryItems categoryItems = new CategoryItems(
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['CategoryName'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['MarketPrice'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['OurPrice'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['TotalDiscount'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['Weight']);
        categoryItemList.add(categoryItems);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.black, //or set color with: Color(0xFF0000FF)
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: categoriesOnlyList.length, // place breakpoint here
          itemBuilder: (context, index1) {
            if (categoriesOnlyList == null || categoriesOnlyList.length == 0) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator(); // you should see loading animation if list is empty
            }

            return Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                categoriesOnlyList[index1].Name,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: categoryItemList.length, // place breakpoint here
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (categoryItemList == null || categoryItemList.length == 0) {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator(); // you should see loading animation if list is empty
                    }

                    return categoriesOnlyList[index1].Name ==
                            categoryItemList[index].CategoryName
                        ? Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              height: 200,
                              width: 200,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                              child: Card(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  child: Text(
                                    categoryItemList[index].Name,
                                    style: TextStyle(),
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        : Container();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The solution would be to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Word of warning: The application will run the build method multiple times, it's good practice to place anything you don't want to be repeatedly called (like database calls or changing system overlays) outside of the method.

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.black, // or set color with: Color(0xFF0000FF)
  ),
);
```

Comment: I really Appreciate your answer, but I think there is some other problem because even I'm not able to see my hard coded Text value untill I reload it.